# Magento - set currency when creating order programatically?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a dev magento with multi-currency enabled (GBP, EUR , USD). I am trying to create a sales order against my dev magento in **Euro** - however the order keeps creating in GBP (my base currency).

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Here's my code so far:

```
<?php

// Init Magento In Admin Store Context
require_once '/home/www-data/public_html/app/Mage.php';
$app = Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

// Function To Generate Magento Sales Order
function CreateOrder($orderData = array())
{
    // Validate Order Data
    if (!sizeof($orderData)) {
        exit('Invalid Order Data');
    }
    $orderData = (object)$orderData;
    if (!sizeof($orderData->BasketData)) {
        exit('Sales Order Basket Cannot Be Empty');
    }

    // Anticipate Error
    try
    {
        // Start New Sales Order Quote
        $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
                 ->setStoreId($orderData->StoreId);

        // Set Sales Order Quote Currency
        $quote->setCurrency($orderData->Currency);

        // Load Sales Order Customer
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                    ->setWebsiteId($orderData->CustomerWebsiteId)
                    ->load($orderData->CustomerId);

        // Assign Customer To Sales Order Quote
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer);

        // Configure Notification
        $quote->setSendCconfirmation($orderData->SendConfirmation ? '1' : '0');

        // Add Products To Sales Order Quote
        foreach ($orderData->BasketData as $orderLine)
        {
            // Add Product To Sales Order Quote
            $quote->addProduct(
                Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($orderLine['ProductId']),
                new Varien_Object(array(
                    'price' => floatval($orderLine['Price']),
                    'qty'   => intval($orderLine['Qty'])
                ))
            );
        }

        // Set Sales Order Billing Address
        $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData(array(
            'firstname'  => $orderData->BillingAddress['Firstname'],
            'lastname'   => $orderData->BillingAddress['Lastname'],
            'company'    => $orderData->BillingAddress['Company'],
            'street'     => array($orderData->BillingAddress['AddressLine1'], $orderData->BillingAddress['AddressLine2']),
            'region_id'  => 0,
            'region'     => $orderData->BillingAddress['Region'],
            'city'       => $orderData->BillingAddress['City'],
            'postcode'   => $orderData->BillingAddress['Postcode'],
            'country_id' => getCountryId($orderData->BillingAddress['Country']),
            'telephone'  => $orderData->BillingAddress['Telephone']
        ));

        // Set Sales Order Shipping Address
        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData(array(
            'firstname'  => $orderData->ShippingAddress['Firstname'],
            'lastname'   => $orderData->ShippingAddress['Lastname'],
            'company'    => $orderData->ShippingAddress['Company'],
            'street'     => array($orderData->ShippingAddress['AddressLine1'], $orderData->ShippingAddress['AddressLine2']),
            'region_id'  => 0,
            'region'     => $orderData->ShippingAddress['Region'],
            'city'       => $orderData->ShippingAddress['City'],
            'postcode'   => $orderData->ShippingAddress['Postcode'],
            'country_id' => getCountryId($orderData->ShippingAddress['Country']),
            'telephone'  => $orderData->ShippingAddress['Telephone']
        ));

        // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
        $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                        ->collectShippingRates()
                        ->setShippingMethod($orderData->ShippingMethod)
                        ->setPaymentMethod($orderData->PaymentMethod);

        // Set Sales Order Payment
        $quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => $orderData->PaymentMethod));

        // Collect Totals & Save Quote
        $quote->collectTotals()->save();

        // Create Order From Quote
        $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
        $service->submitAll();
        $increment_id = $service->getOrder()->getIncrementId();

        // Resource Clean-Up
        $quote = $customer = $service = null;

        // Finished
        return $increment_id;
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        // Error
        exit($e->getMessage());
    }
}

// HELPER FUNCTION
function getCountryId($countryName) {
    $countryId = '';
    $countryCollection = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->getCollection();
    foreach ($countryCollection as $country) {
        if ($countryName == $country->getName()) {
            $countryId = $country->getCountryId();
            break;
        }
    }
    $countryCollection = null;
    return $countryId;
}

// TEST Order Create Function
echo CreateOrder(array(
    'Currency'          => 'EUR', // Euro
    'StoreId'           => 3,     // Trade Store View
    'CustomerWebsiteId' => 2,     // Trade Website
    'CustomerId'        => 5,     // Latheesan K.
    'SendConfirmation'  => false,
    'BasketData'        => array
    (
        array('ProductId' => 3, 'Price' => 13.00, 'Qty' => 1), // VCF001
        array('ProductId' => 6, 'Price' =>  1.00, 'Qty' => 1), // VCF002
        array('ProductId' => 8, 'Price' => 14.99, 'Qty' => 1), // VCF003
    ),
    'BillingAddress'    => array
    (
        'Firstname'     => 'Latheesan',
        'Lastname'      => 'Kanes',
        'Company'       => 'Intelli B.I. Ltd',
        'AddressLine1'  => 'Unit 1, Eastman Road',
        'AddressLine2'  => 'Acton',
        'Region'        => '',
        'City'          => 'London',
        'Postcode'      => 'W3 7QS',
        'Country'       => 'United Kingdom',
        'Telephone'     => '0208 428 2832',
    ),
    'ShippingAddress'   => array
    (
        'Firstname'     => 'Latheesan',
        'Lastname'      => 'Kanes',
        'Company'       => 'Intelli B.I. Ltd',
        'AddressLine1'  => 'Unit 1, Eastman Road',
        'AddressLine2'  => 'Acton',
        'Region'        => '',
        'City'          => 'London',
        'Postcode'      => 'W3 7QS',
        'Country'       => 'United Kingdom',
        'Telephone'     => '0208 428 2832',
    ),
    'ShippingMethod'    => 'flatrate_flatrate',
    'PaymentMethod'     => 'checkmo'
));

?>
```

Also, this line isn't turning on email notification on order create:

```
// Configure Notification
$quote->setSendCconfirmation($orderData->SendConfirmation ? '1' : '0');
```

How do you enable email notification?

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to set the currency to the current store of the order like that

`Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->setCurrentCurrency(Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->load('CHF'));`

It must be defined before `$quote->collectTotals()->save();`

Answer (score 0):

You have one store with 3 currencies or multiple stores with one currency? If you have second option must select store with proper currency, now you set base store with base currency so magento creates order with GBP

```
$app = Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

Or maybe try something like that (first option)?

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
->setIncrementId($reservedOrderId)
->setStoreId($storeId)
->setQuoteId(0)
->setGlobal_currency_code('USD')
->setBase_currency_code('USD')
->setStore_currency_code('USD')
->setOrder_currency_code('USD');
//Set your store currency USD or any other
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the quote, you can use this:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
$currency = Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->load('USD'); 
$quote->setForcedCurrency($currency);
```